# Can't resolve domain names starting with a dash 

Tags: url

I (and many other users) can't access pages which URL contains a dash in its subdomain ; example : fragmented---.deviantart.com

- Checked with other OS : there's a page really dwelling here. And you can verify that deviantart normally sends you a 404 page.
- Checked with many web browsers : it doesn't work with ubuntu neither debian.

Comment: I would try `curl http://fragmented---.deviantart.com/` as well

Answer (score 4):

There is a [Launchpad Bug (#668926)](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/668926) on the subject. A similar case (just the name *starts* with the hyphen).

Following the discussion the problem seems to be rooted in different levels of standards compliance.

Linux seems to follow strictly [RFC 952](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc952):

> A "name" (Net, Host, Gateway, or Domain name) is a text string up to
> 24 characters drawn from the alphabet (A-Z), digits (0-9), minus sign
> (-), and period (.).  Note that periods are only allowed when they
> serve to delimit components of "domain style names". [...] No blank or
> space characters are permitted as part of a name. No distinction is
> made between upper and lower case.  **The first character must be an
> alpha character.  The last character must not be a minus sign or
> period.**

Whereas there are standards that are more relaxed about the domain naming conventions. In [Comment #7](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/668926/comments/7) further RFCs are listed, that contain rules more loose than 952 (and some seem to contradict each other).

It's strange while you can `nslookup` such names, you cannot `ping` or `wget` them.

The next surprising thing is if you add this host name to `/etc/hosts/` you can `ping` it, even browse the website. Add the following line to `/etc/hosts` (`sudo YOUR-FAVOURITE-TEXT-EDITOR /etc/hosts`, but be careful, create a backup first.):

```
199.15.160.100  fragmented---.deviantart.com
```

Now fire up your favourite browser and follow http://fragmented---.deviantart.com/.