# Can't view URLs that contain hyphens before them

Tags: 12.04, browser, dns

Some Tumblr URLs contain hyphens before them (`-example.tumblr.com`). In Windows, I was able to view these URLs without any issue. In Ubuntu, I've tested it in Chromium, Chrome, Firefox, and Opera so I've come to the conclusion that the problem is Ubuntu. What can I do? Does anyone else have this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is duplicated of [Can't resolve domain names starting with a dash](https://askubuntu.com/questions/123169/cant-resolve-domain-names-starting-with-a-dash)

Basically linux follows a stricter domain naming convention. You should be able to solve it by adding the dashed domain to your /etc/hosts